# kubernetes build/run.sh fails on ubuntu 16.04 with !!! Error in build/../build/common.sh:546

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes

When trying to run `build/run.sh` on ubuntu 16.04 it fails with the below error message, any ideas?

```
~/dev/kubernetes$ build/run.sh 
+++ [0117 15:45:56] Verifying Prerequisites....
+++ [0117 15:45:56] Building Docker image kube-build:build-226b89c8c0-4-v1.7.4-1
+++ [0117 15:46:57] Keeping container amazing_ptolemy
+++ [0117 15:46:57] Keeping container amazing_ptolemy
+++ [0117 15:46:57] Keeping container amazing_ptolemy
+++ [0117 15:46:57] Keeping image kube-build:build-226b89c8c0-4-v1.7.4-1
+++ [0117 15:46:57] Creating data container kube-build-data-226b89c8c0-4-v1.7.4-1
+++ [0117 15:47:05] Syncing sources to container
+++ [0117 15:47:05] Stopping any currently running rsyncd container
+++ [0117 15:47:05] Starting rsyncd container
+++ [0117 15:47:07] Running rsync
+++ [0117 15:47:20] Stopping any currently running rsyncd container
+++ [0117 15:47:20] Running build command...
Invalid input - please specify a command to run.
!!! Error in build/../build/common.sh:546
  'return 4' exited with status 4
Call stack:
  1: build/../build/common.sh:546 kube::build::run_build_command(...)
  2: build/run.sh:30 main(...)
Exiting with status 1



$ docker info
Containers: 2
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 2
Images: 15
Server Version: 1.12.6
Storage Driver: aufs
 Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/aufs
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Dirs: 31
 Dirperm1 Supported: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: null overlay bridge host
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Security Options: apparmor seccomp
Kernel Version: 4.4.0-59-generic
Operating System: Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 1
Total Memory: 2.886 GiB
Name: tomerb-VirtualBox
ID: 32UH:TVHM:FTSL:ZPZV:PHJH:FA2Y:LPSG:YZZW:TLUU:J6TQ:W5JF:SBKW
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
WARNING: No swap limit support
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is triggered within the script when checking the available arguments. As the error `Invalid input - please specify a command to run.` states you should use a subcommand / argument for the script as described in the [README](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/build)

- `build/run.sh make`: Build just linux binaries in the container. Pass options and packages as necessary.
- `build/run.sh make cross`: Build all binaries for all platforms
- `build/run.sh make test`: Run all unit tests
- `build/run.sh make test-integration`: Run integration test
- `build/run.sh make test-cmd`: Run CLI tests